# Help installing Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo B570. Won't Boot

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, boot-repair

I'm attempting to install the latest version of Ubuntu desktop, 16.04 LST, on my old laptop, a Lenovo B570. Originally it ran windows 7, and I upgraded to windows 10 when it was free.

I downloaded version 16.04 and created a live USB using rufus to install the image. In rufus, I left all the settings as default, other than selecting the image file and the drive. The only BIOS boot settings my laptop has is the boot order. I don't have any ability to change between UEFI or BIOS mode, or secure boot, or any other options like that.

I changed the boot order and was able to boot from the live USB. From there, I selected the "Try Ubuntu" option and everything seemed to be working fine. It booted into Ubuntu and everything was functioning correctly. From the Ubuntu desktop, I installed Ubuntu on the laptop, choosing not to dual boot and erasing windows. Once that process was completed I restarted the laptop which led to the issue.

Instead of booting into Ubuntu or grub, I booted to the live USB menu again, even after changing the boot order in the bios to prefer the HDD. If I attempted to boot without the USB drive I would just be taken to the BIOS boot menu. Ubuntu would not boot. To fix this I've tried:

- reinstalling Ubuntu the same way,
- Running boot repair
- Using gparted to erase all partitions on the hard drive, then reinstalling
- Holding down and tapping shift, space, and escape individually in an attempt to access grub, unsuccessfully

None of these actions have seemed to have any effect. Here is the boot info summary created from my most recent boot repair attempt:

https://paste2.org/BPjg5Gkk

Any help would be greatly appreciated as at this point I'm at a loss as to what to do next. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried reseting your BIOS settings to defaults? Then, try installing UBUNTU withouth changing boot order. Most BIOS give you a boot menu when pressing F12, F8 or F10 (you can see other options here: https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=58779).

Answer (score 0):

Your disk uses GPT partitioning, so there is no room for a legacy bootloader outside the partitions.  You have to explicitly make a small (1-2M) partition and flag it grub-bios so the bootloader can be fully installed.

---

I'd just reinstall and re-do the partitions, putting the grub-bios one just after the EFI partition.  Then if you'd like to keep your data separate from the rest of the system, use 50G for the root, and the rest for your home data.  There are lots of recommendations on setting up your partitions, depends upon how you are going to use them.

Comment: Would you suggest making this new partition and then running boot repair? What file system should this partition be. Sorry if these seem like obvious questions. I'm still a novice.